# Canvas typescript error

Tags: javascript, typescript, canvas

I have this code:

```
convertToDataURLviaCanvas(url, outputFormat){
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
      let img = new Image();
      img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
      img.onload = function(){
        let canvas: any = document.createElement('CANVAS'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        dataURL;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        canvas.width = this.width;
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
        //callback(dataURL);
        canvas = null;
        resolve(dataURL); 
      };
      img.src = url;
    });
  }
```

The problem is that this.height and this.width appear underline in visual studio code and the error says: La propiedad 'width' no existe en el tipo 'HTMLElement'. The code works but i have this annoying red underlines is there a way by code to remove them, maybe putting some type different to any in canvas.

Comment: try using `img.height` and `img.width`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is there because there is no guarantee that the assigned method will have the same context as the scope it is defined within. `this` could theoretically be anything.

You can resolve this by using `img.width` and `img.height` instead of `this`. This causes `img` to be captured by the method assigned to `onload`, and will always refer to that object.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem as well with typescript in Angular5, in which case i couldn't compile at all. I solved the problem by creating a new interface with the required fields and casting the objects having the problem to it like this:

```
interface MyType extends HTMLElement 
{
    width: number;
    height: number;
}

let canvas: MyType = <MyType> document.createElement('CANVAS')
```

if i well remember this should solve the problem